# With Minecraft Xbox 360 version, am I able to voice chat with my friend without using the phone?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My friend and I both got the Xbox 360 version of Minecraft so we could play with each other without going to each other's house. I wanted to play while chatting to him without using the phone. Am I able to do that? And if so, how?

Comment: Are you aware Xbox 360 has a Party feature? When you say phone, are you talking about a telephone or headphones? This really doesn't have anything to do with Minecraft, but has to do with exploiting Xbox's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The Xbox 360 supports voice chat.

Things you can use:

- A microphone with a USB
- A Bluetooth device with a microphone like a headset. [This link](http://www.xbox.com/en-CA/Xbox360/Accessories/HeadsetsCommunication/Xbox360WirelessHeadsetWithBluetooth) is a useful 
  device.
- Xbox Kinect

[Source](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/connecting-headsets)

The source will help you. I can not type it all without device crashing.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Kinect, use the a microphone and camera. Also, you could use a wireless or non wireless headset. [Source](http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/13/microsoft-kinect-gets-official/)